# How to merge a NFTS partition cut into two pieces?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, resizing

I have a Dual Boot O.S. in a NVMe SSD and I also have a 500GB HDD that had an old computer; that HDD had 3 partitions (A, B and C) and I decided to delete partition A in order to create my linux backups there.

Once I deleted partition A I wanted to expand partition B, for which I used Windows 10 disk management tool, but by expanding partition B, it was created at the start of the HDD disk, which I didn’t want and now it looks as horrible as this:

[image]

How do I move Partitions B and merge them ?
[image]

I already tried:

- To use [NIUUB](https://www.hdd-tool.com/index.html) but it didn't work (0% after long time several times)
- To use [KDE partition manager](https://apps.kde.org/es/partitionmanager/): it doesn't recognize the partitions
- To use [Gparted](https://gparted.org/): Same as KDE
- Another tool whose name I don't longer remember

## KDE

[image]

## GParted

[image]

## General info

(Another SSD but don't mind that)

```
lsblk
 
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda           8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    0    37G  0 part 
├─sda2        8:2    0 175.8G  0 part 
└─sda3        8:3    0 192.3G  0 part 
sdb           8:16   0 223.6G  0 disk 
├─sdb1        8:17   0   499M  0 part 
├─sdb2        8:18   0    99M  0 part 
├─sdb3        8:19   0    16M  0 part 
└─sdb4        8:20   0   223G  0 part 
zram0       252:0    0     8G  0 disk [SWAP]
nvme0n1     259:0    0 953.9G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   100M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0    16M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0 474.7G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─nvme0n1p5 259:5    0   478G  0 part /home
                                      /
```

```
sudo parted -l

Model: ATA Hitachi HDP72505 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Numero  Inicio  Fin    Tamaño  Typo     Sistema de ficheros  Banderas
 1      32.3kB  500GB  500GB   primary  ntfs


Model: ATA KINGSTON SA400S3 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 240GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Numero  Inicio  Fin    Tamaño  Sistema de ficheros  Nombre                        Banderas
 1      1049kB  524MB  523MB   ntfs                 Basic data partition          oculta, diag
 2      524MB   628MB  104MB   fat32                EFI system partition          arranque, esp
 3      628MB   645MB  16.8MB                       Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 4      645MB   240GB  239GB   ntfs                 Basic data partition          msftdata


Model: XPG SPECTRIX S40G (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 1024GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Numero  Inicio  Fin     Tamaño  Sistema de ficheros  Nombre                        Banderas
 1      1049kB  106MB   105MB   fat32                EFI System Partition          arranque, esp
 2      106MB   123MB   16.8MB                       Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 3      123MB   510GB   510GB   ntfs                 Basic data partition          msftdata
 4      510GB   511GB   1074MB  ext4
 5      511GB   1024GB  513GB   btrfs


Model: Desconocida (unknown)
Disk /dev/zram0: 8590MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096B/4096B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Numero  Inicio  Fin     Tamaño  Sistema de ficheros  Banderas
 1      0.00B   8590MB  8590MB  linux-swap(v1)
```

```
sudo fdisk -l

Disco /dev/sda: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectores
Modelo de disco: Hitachi HDP72505
Unidades: sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamaño de sector (lógico/físico): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tamaño de E/S (mínimo/óptimo): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tipo de etiqueta de disco: dos
Identificador del disco: 0x83b45540

Disposit.  Inicio Comienzo     Final  Sectores Tamaño Id Tipo
/dev/sda1               63 976771119 976771057 465.8G 42 SFS


Disco /dev/sdb: 223.57 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectores
Modelo de disco: KINGSTON SA400S3
Unidades: sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamaño de sector (lógico/físico): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tamaño de E/S (mínimo/óptimo): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tipo de etiqueta de disco: gpt
Identificador del disco: C52C1C3E-6014-4249-8E9A-FA338A3FBC56

Disposit.  Comienzo     Final  Sectores Tamaño Tipo
/dev/sdb1      2048   1023999   1021952   499M Entorno de recuperación de Windows
/dev/sdb2   1024000   1226751    202752    99M Sistema EFI
/dev/sdb3   1226752   1259519     32768    16M Reservado para Microsoft
/dev/sdb4   1259520 468860927 467601408   223G Datos básicos de Microsoft


Disco /dev/nvme0n1: 953.87 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectores
Modelo de disco: XPG SPECTRIX S40G                       
Unidades: sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamaño de sector (lógico/físico): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tamaño de E/S (mínimo/óptimo): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tipo de etiqueta de disco: gpt
Identificador del disco: 8A0086F6-F017-42FB-8711-97C94E203ADF

Disposit.       Comienzo      Final   Sectores Tamaño Tipo
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048     206847     204800   100M Sistema EFI
/dev/nvme0n1p2    206848     239615      32768    16M Reservado para Microsoft
/dev/nvme0n1p3    239616  995816720  995577105 474.7G Datos básicos de Microsoft
/dev/nvme0n1p4 995817472  997914623    2097152     1G Sistema de ficheros de Linux
/dev/nvme0n1p5 997914624 2000408575 1002493952   478G Sistema de ficheros de Linux


Disco /dev/zram0: 8 GiB, 8589934592 bytes, 2097152 sectores
Unidades: sectores de 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Tamaño de sector (lógico/físico): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Tamaño de E/S (mínimo/óptimo): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

Comment: Lots of info (which is very good), but please note that it is better to post actual (code formatted) text for command outputs, rather than screen shots (as a screen shot is not text searchable). Please [edit] and post the commands' outputs as text.

Comment: You used Windows 10 disk management tool, but how come your screenshots are from Linux? What kind of disk and partitions did you have before and now, and how exactly did you expand B?

Comment: @harrymc I've a Dual boot system; In [this blog](https://www.diskpart.com/windows-10/windows-10-disk-management-0528.html#3) shows the things that I did